# Python Loop to find a substring in a list

Tags: python

I am pretty new to python, hoping to get some help on constructing a loop to perform the following:

The problem basically boils down to:  Lets say I have a list of account names:

```
[ ‘Roman Roy MD’ , ‘Tom and Jerry Dermatology Associates’ , ‘University of North Carolina Hospital’ ]
```

I want to test each element of the list against a cross table of keywords:

```
Keyword       ReturnValue
MD            single doc practice
University    hospital system
Associates    group practice
```

And then return the `ReturnValue` based on whether the `keyword` is in the Account Name.

I suppose I can make a dictionary out of the table (with keyword / return as key : value pairs). Then it would be a loop that looks for the ‘key’ in the Account Name, and if there is a match, then returns the ‘return value’. It is structuring the loop that I get hung-up on.

I have tried the following:

```
accts = ["Roy Geronemus MD" , "Tom Jerry Dermatology Associates" , "University of North Carolina Hospital" ]

values = {
            "MD"  : "Single Doctor Practice" , "University" : "Hospital System" , "Associates" : "Group Practice"
          }

for x in accts:
    if x.contains(values.keys(), na=False, regex=True):
        print(values.values())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends entirely on what you are trying to do with this information. You are on the right track with this though. Maintaining this mapping is essential which you have already done with the dictionary. The next step is what do you plan on doing with that information? You said you want the 'ReturnValue' returned to you, this just means make a function.

```
keyword_mapping = {
    "MD"  : "Single Doctor Practice" ,
    "University" : "Hospital System" ,
    "Associates" : "Group Practice"
}
accounts = [ ‘Roman Roy MD’ , ‘Tom and Jerry Dermatology Associates’ , ‘University of North Carolina Hospital’ ]

def check_keywords(account):
    for key, val in keyword_mapping.items():
        """ Splitting Name Into Tokens Means That Keyword Mapping 
            Will Only Take Place On A Word Basis And Not Within Words"""
        tokens = account.split()
        if key in tokens:
            """ If Possible Or You Want To Return 
                More Than One Match Here, You Can Create List
                Or Change Return To 'yield' And Use A Generator"""
            return val
for account in accounts:
    rValue = check_keywords(account)
    if rValue is None:
        print("Account: {0} Has No Matching Keywords".format(account)
    else:
        print("Account: {0} Has Matching Keyword: {1}".format(account, rValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the dictionary, testing each keyword separately.

```
for x in accts:
    for key, value in values.items():
        if key in x:
            print (x, value)
            break
```

Comment: is entries new in Python3.8 or something? or am I missing something? shouldn't it be items?

Comment: I'm not actually a Python programmer, I just play one on the Internet. :)

Comment: Could've fooled me XD

Answer (score 0):

for the sake of throwing in a nasty one-liner list comprehension, you can achieve a list output of all the accs/vals like so:

```
[[acc,values[key]] for acc in accs for key in values.keys() if key in acc]
```

output:

```
[['Roman Roy MD', 'Single Doctor Practice'], ['Tom and Jerry Dermatology Associates', 'Group Practice'], ['University of North Carolina Hospital', 'Hospital System']]
```

Comment: this solution will probably work in most cases, but first post seems a little more robust. this helps me understand list comprehension more thoroughly - i appreciate your input / help.